# Can you make two columns equal if a condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, conditional-statements, finance

```
df1 = 
Profit, Qualified 
1000, TRUE 
2000, FALSE 
3000, FALSE 
4000, TRUE
```

Desired output:

```
df1= 
Profit, Qualified, Qualified Profit 
1000, TRUE, 1000 
2000, FALSE, 0 
3000, FALSE, 0 
4000, TRUE, 4000
```

Two lines of code i have tried:

```
df1['Qualified Profit'] = df1['Profit'].where(df1['Qualified'] == "TRUE")

df1['Qualified Profit'] = df1.apply(lambda x: x['Profit'] if x["Qualified"]=="TRUE" else '0', axis=1)
```

Comment: Use `df1['Qualified Profit'] = np.where(df1['Qualified'] == "TRUE", df1['Profit'], 0)`

Comment: I have tried this but I get an error 'invalid type comparison'

Comment: ok, so need `df1['Qualified Profit'] = np.where(df1['Qualified'], df1['Profit'], 0)`

Comment: How did it know to pick the 'TRUE' values ?

Comment: If use `df1['Qualified']` here is is same like `df1['Qualified'] == True `